# Is it correct to use the infinitive to in the next sentences with give and spit?

Tags: grammar

Greetings to all of you I have the next question

I have these two sentences:
*My life was safe with the love you gave to me*

and

*you now feel free to spit your sins to me*

Is the use of the infinitive "to" correct or should I use: Gave me and spit me?

Comment: Related, and required reading for the question's OP: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103529/13804

Comment: You don't spit sins  in English. You can, however, spill them to someone, meaning tell them about your sins.

Answer (score 2):

As a comment already pointed out, this is not infinitive to, it is simply preposition. You do not need the preposition for *"gave me"*, but *"spit me"* is not common, and may cause someone to think **me** is the thing **being spit**.

It is interesting word choice to say *"spit to me"*, as the phrase is nearly always *"spit **at** me"*, but with this word choice, the sentence seems more poetic in a way. Spitting sins **to** me sounds much less aggressive than spitting sins **at** me, but I see no reason why one could not spit something to someone.