# What is the grammatical function/ part of speech of "to increase funding" and "to help countries adapt?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the grammatical function/ part of speech of "to increase funding" and "to help countries adapt?"

> The United States has been under pressure to increase funding to help countries adapt to climate risks already upon them.

Comment: They look like [***Adverbs of Purpose***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbs-of-Purpose.htm#:~:text=Adverbs%20of%20purpose%20(sometimes%20called,verbs%2C%20adjectives%2C%20or%20adverbs.) to me. (***Why*** is the US under pressure? ***Why*** should the funding be increased?).

Comment: Welcome! Can you help us by editing your question to include what you think about these phrases so far?

Comment: They're prepositional phrases.

Comment: @Hot Licks What are? 'To' followed by a base-form verb?

Comment: 'Be under pressure' is a verbo-nominal multi word verb taking a to-infinitival clause. << X [is/are/was/will be ... under pressure] [to stay at home] / [to pay for their upkeep] / [to take the course] / [to self-isolate] / .... >> cf  << X [wants / wishes / hates / ...] [to sleep late / to do the dishes / to be warm / ....>> which use a simplex (one-word) verb.

Comment: They both belong to the category (your part of speech) 'infinitival clause', and they are both functioning as 'purpose adjuncts'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Ask my 3rd grade teacher.

Comment: As @BillJ said, they're purpose infinitives, like the last two words of _He stopped to smoke_, which does not mean the opposite of  _He started to smoke_ like _He stopped smoking_ does.

Comment: @Hot Licks (In response to "Ask my 3rd grade teacher.") Get another 3rd grade teacher.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Since I was in 3rd grade English terminology has changed considerably.

Comment: @Hot Licks It's fundamental syntax, not terminology. Araucaria on ELL explains: [How to use preposition 'to' / infinitive-to ...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40982/how-to-use-preposition-to-infinitive-to-and-ing). But it's appeared here too: [When is _to_ a preposition and when the infinitive marker?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103529/when-is-to-a-preposition-and-when-the-infinitive-marker) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To increase funding* and *to help countries adapt* are *to*-infinitive constructions.

[We follow certain adjectives—such as happy, pleased, relieved, sad, reluctant, and surprised—with *to*-infinitives](http://www.grammaring.com/adjective-to-infinitive). It happens that [*under pressure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under%20pressure) is a prepositional phrase idiom functioning like these adjectives here. You can swap one in to see:

> *The United States has been **reluctant** to increase funding to help countries adapt to climate risks already upon them.*

The pattern there is noun (*the United States*)  + linking verb (*has been*) + adjective (*under pressure*) + *to*-infinitive (*to increase*).

*To help* is an [infinitive of purpose](https://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose) here. It functions like an adverb to answer the “why”:

> *Why increase funding? Increase funding **[in order] to help** countries adapt...*

Answer (score 0):

> The United States has been under pressure to increase funding [in order] to help countries adapt to climate risks [that are] already upon them.

The United States -subject

has been - verb

under pressure - prepositional modifier (adjectival) as complement

to do this  -  infinitive as prepositional adverbial modifying "under pressure"

**{**[in order] - introducing a subordinate clause of purpose

to help -

countries - noun, object of "to help"

[to] adapt [infinitive complement of "help"]

to climate risks -  prepositional adverbial modifier modifying "adapt"

[that are] already upon them. - relative clause modifying "climate risks".**}** subordinate clause of purpose (adjectival)