# A to-infinitive is formed with 'to' plus the base form of a verb. What part of speech does 'to' belong to?

Tags: parts-of-speech, infinitive-constructions

> *I want to go home.*

Here the word *to* belongs to what part of speech?

Comment: The "to" is not part of the verb, but a **subordinator**, a special marker for verb phrases of infinitival clauses.

Comment: Closely connected: [When is 'to' a preposition and when the infinitive-marker?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103529/when-is-to-a-preposition-and-when-the-infinitive-marker) // I'll edit to correct your title soon; 'go' is a 'base form' or 'bare infinitive'; 'to go' is a 'to-infinitive'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'Preposition' and 'marker' are not in competition, the first being a word category (POS), the other a function. This is why it is so important to distinguish category and function.

Comment: @BillJ Your comments make perfectly good answers (although they would benefit from corroboration with a text book, that doesn't invalidate an answer). Please use the answer box for answers rather than the comment box.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It was a comment directed at Edwin, not intended as an answer to the OP. I did cite a source in my comment on Fev's answer.

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps I wasn't clear, but I was referring to your initial comment, which actually answers the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, yes, I forgot about my first comment! I'll post an answer asap.

Comment: 'Preposition' and 'infinitive-marker' are not in competition if one accepts the analysis and terminology chosen by CGEL. There are competing views.

Comment: No one would want to claim that 'marker' is a part of speech. But preposition certainly is.

Comment: Only if you choose to call it 'a part of speech'. These are not discovered properties; these are theoretical terms and make theoretical claims, many of which are not generally accepted. So naming without qualification is counterproductive.

Comment: The terms are well established, so I see no reason to argue otherwise.

Comment: I love to play cards, I love playing cards. Surely "to" is a function word there.

Comment: Etymonline offers an interesting angle on this question.  It calls it a preposition:-  "Old English to "in the direction of, for the purpose of, furthermore," from West Germanic *to. ... The nearly universal use of to with infinitives (to sleep, to dream, etc.) arose in Middle English out of the Old English dative use of to, and it helped drive out the Old English inflectional endings (though in this use to itself is a mere sign, without meaning). ..."  I note that West Indian creole actually jettisons the 'to' with no loss of the intended sense.

Answer (score 3):

> *I want to go home.*

I'd say that infinitival "to" belongs to the word category (POS) 'subordinator', and its function is that of 'marker', a meaningless element that simply introduces the VP.

It functions in much the same way as the indisputable subordinators "that", as in *I know that she lent him the money"* and "whether", as in *I'm unsure whether it will rain.*

Note that infinitival "to" derives historically from the preposition "to" (notice the strong similarity between *I went **to** the doctor* and *I went **to** see the doctor*) but long ago lost its prepositional properties.

Answer (score 1):

It belongs to no morphological category, that's why it is named ***a particle***.

> The usual definition of particle is that it is ***a word that does not clearly belong to any other word class*** - though the expression is also used for the type of adverb particle found in phrasal and phrasal prepositional verbs. English has two such particles, ***the infinitive particle TO*** and ***the negative particle NOT***. ([source](http://eltnotebook.blogspot.com/2016/03/an-elt-glossary-particle-infinitive.html#:%7E:text=The%20infinitive%20particle%20is%20to,Thursday%3B%20It%27s%20impossible%20to%20go.))

It is not a preposition, neither is it a part of the verb, as [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/02/infinitive-2.html) shows:

> The infinitive is the uninflected or basic form of a verb, and “to” is not part of it. When “to” appears with an infinitive, it is generally referred to as an “***infinitive marker***” or “***infinitive particle***”; it is not part of the verb and is not always used.

The same site cites reputable sources in support of this:

> Fowler’s *Modern English Usage* (rev. 3rd ed.), describes two uses of the infinitive: (a) “the to-infinitive,” in which “to” is described as a “***particle***,” and (b) “the bare or simple or plain infinitive.”
>
> The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* explains that:
>
> > The traditional practice for citation of verbs is to cite them with the infinitival marker ***to***, as in *‘to be,’ ‘to take,’* and so on. That is an unsatisfactory convention, because the ***to*** *is not part of the verb itself*.
>
> The word “***to***” here “is not a (morphological) prefix but a quite separate (syntactic) word,” Pullum and Huddleston say, adding:
>
> > This is evident from the fact that it can stand alone in elliptical constructions (as in *I haven’t read it yet, but I hope **to** shortly*), need not be repeated in coordination (as seen in *I want to go out and get some exercise*), and can be separated from the verb by an adverb, as seen in the so-called ‘split infinitive construction,’ *I’m trying **to** gradually improve my game*.

The site cites similar explanations from other established dictionaries, I will not quote them all here. But I cannot omit the OED entry they quote, as it shows the morphological shift of this particle:

> Quote from the OED:
>
> > The infinitive with *to* may be dependent on an adj., a n., or a vb., or it may stand independently. ***To an adj. it stands in adverbial relation***: *ready to fight = ready for fighting*; ***to a n. it stands in adjectival or sometimes adverbial relation***: *a day to remember = a memorable day*; ***to a vb. it may stand in an adverbial or substantival relation***: *to proceed to work = to proceed to working; to like to work = to like working*.”
>
> When this ***preposition*** was first used in English as an *infinitive marker* (***tó*** in Old English), it did have ***a prepositional flavor***.
> *“I prepared to eat”* sounded to the medieval ear something like *“I prepared for eating”*; *“he fails to think”* sounded something like *“he fails in thinking”*; *“we strive to please”* sounded something like *“we strive toward pleasing.”* As the OED says,
>
> > it expressed motion, direction, inclination, purpose, etc., toward the act or condition expressed by the infinitive; as in ‘*he came to help (i.e. to the help of) his friends*,’ … ‘*he prepared to depart (i.e. for departure)*.’
>
> There once was a sense of motion, of moving toward accomplishing something (represented by the infinitive), if that makes any sense. But as the OED says:
>
> > ***in process of time this obvious sense of the prep. became weakened and generalized, so that tó became at last the ordinary link expressing any prepositional relation in which an infinitive stands to a preceding verb, adjective, or substantive.*** [Here the italicized tó represents the Old English word.]

PS: The research I have just done for this answer makes me wonder: then why on earth is the ***to-infinitive*** also called [***full infinitive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive)? But that's maybe worth asking in a different post.

Comment: In my experience, 'particle' is not a word category (POS), but a general term for those words (usually preps) that occur between a verb and its direct object, as in "They took **down** the suitcases". Infinitival "to" actually belongs to the POS 'subordinator', and its function is that of 'marker'. That accords with H&P in CGEL.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, it's true this is how CGEL chooses to classify it. But you will agree that it is a terribly anomalous subordinator: It attaches pre-VP, not clause-initially; it co-occurs with another Subordinator, "for" ; it strands under ellipsis. So in fact, I am not sure anything is gained by putting it in any category at all.

Comment: When CGEL was being written, GKP felt strongly that it was an auxiliary verb, but RDH's view prevailed. Still, in the overall scheme of things, it hardly seems worth losing any sleep over -- unlike the Russia/Ukraine crisis!

Comment: :) ... I suscribe to that!

Comment: @BillJ Is that common knowledge now?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't think any harm is done, at least I hope not!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who you ask. Within the confines of traditional *parts of speech*, the present-day *to* in the infinitive may be a preposition or it may a particle.

Even in the 19th century, grammarians were wary of assigning the to-infinitive to a single part of speech. For example, if you look up *preposition* in George Pliny Brown's 1899 book *[Advanced Pages of Elements of English Grammar](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Advanced_Pages_of_Elements_of_English_Gr/jRFMAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover)*, you would find nothing resembling the to-infinitive. Instead, "The Infinitive" would be listed under the hedging header "Words Sometimes Called Parts of Speech" with "The Participle," "The Article," and "The Gerund." Brown describes the infinitive as having some functions of both a verb (in how it can be modified) and a noun phrase (in how it can be the subject of a sentence). In other words, Brown is illustrating the traditional grammarian's difficulty to reconcile the structured *parts of speech* with forms that don't fit well in the existing theory. The *to*-infinitive, let alone *to* itself, is right at that fault line.

The Oxford English Dictionary reflects the difficulty of defining *to* before an infinitive under ["to, prep., conj., and adv.," definition B](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202695). The full explanation is too long to quote in full, but I want to highlight two elements of that explanation:

1. The *to* preceding the infinitive comes from Old English, where it would have been considered a preposition (*tó* [[see Bossworth Toller]](https://bosworthtoller.com/30587)). An example of the preposition-based usage with a verb of motion (*come to*) is under I.1.a.(a) from Bede: "Monige cwomon to bicgenne þa ðing" [Many came to buy the thing]). In that kind of usage, even today, the OED would consider *to* a preposition: "But after an intransitive verb, or the passive voice, *to* is still the preposition."
2. In other uses of the *to*-infinitive not evident in Old English, e.g., using the infinitive as a subject, *to* is considered to have "lost all its meaning, and become a mere 'sign' or prefix of the infinitive." Though the OED wants to call this *to* a prefix, a morphological attachment to the word, that description is quite close to the definition of a *particle*, a word that doesn't fit conveniently into other parts of speech or classes of words ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle#In_English)).

It's worth noting that the OED is not an authority on grammar, and its primary purpose isn't creating rigorous classifications of language use. Nonetheless, it represents what later systems will generally show: while the infinitive *to* once functioned as a preposition, in modern English that language is no longer sufficient to describe what *to* is doing in many infinitive uses. Hence it is often called a *particle*.

Answer (score -3):

'To' in 'to kick' is, according to Wikipedia, an infinitival particle. The infinitive 'to kick' without 'to' so just 'kick' is called the bare infinitive, whilst 'to kick' is called the full infinitive.